# How to make a model in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm beginner and tried to transfer the model to another file, it didn't work for me, suggest me how to do it correctly. The question may seem silly, but if I knew the answer, I would not ask it.

file `todo.controller.js`

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

const data = fs.readFileSync("./data/data.json");
let todos = JSON.parse(data);
class todoController { 
async createTodo(req, res) {
    req.on("data", (data) => {
        const jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
        const title = jsondata.title;
        const description = jsondata.description;
        if ((title, description)) {
          todos.push({
            id: uuidv4(),
            title,
            description,
            dateOfCreate: new Date(),
            lastModified: new Date(),
            check: new Boolean(false),
          });
        fs.writeFile(
          "./data/data.json",
          JSON.stringify(todos, null, 2),
          (err) => {
            if (err) throw error;
          }
        );
      }
    });
  }}
```

file `todo.router.js`

```
const url = require("url");
const todoController = require("../controllers/todo.controller");

const todoRouter = (req, res) => {
  const urlparse = url.parse(req.url, true);

  if (urlparse.pathname == "/todos" && req.method == "POST") {
    todoController.createTodo(req, res);
  }
};
module.exports = todoRouter;
```

here is file `data.json`
[`data.json`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zyJP.png)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what did not work?

Comment: @esQmo_, I tried to create a new const and put in it {id, title, description...check} and move it to another file. I was unable to import links and link all files into a bunch

Comment: Share your data.json file code.

Comment: @ammar, added data.json

Comment: why are you posting your issue again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two separate problems here, separating your code to a different file and also saving or persisting that data somewhere, in this case a file.

You have to create something like a data model and then you have to import it in your other code.

```
// data.js

export const get = async () => {} // we will implement this just now

export const set = async (data) => {} // we will implement this just now

...

// controller.js

import {get, set} from './data.js' // import the methods we just created

...

const createTodo = async (req, res) => {
  req.on("data", (data) => {
    // here you can use get() if you want to use the data

    set(JSON.stringify(data)) // send data to your data model
  }
}
```

Then we also have to actually do something with those methods.

```
// data.js

export const get = async () => {
  // may need to use JSON.parse here depending on how you'll use it
  return fs.readFile('./data.json')
}

export const set = async (data) => {
  fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

So the idea is to have a model responsible for managing the data, retrieving it and saving it, then importing and using those methods in the main controller.  The code above isn't perfect, it's just to show you how to think about it.